# How do I amend this function which converts a decimal int to a binary int, with each of its digits in a array?

Tags: c, arrays, binary, decimal

Let's say I have a temperature in celsius, int tC, and I want to convert that to binary form, with each of the bits in a integer array, arr[5]. I tried to use the remainder by two method to check if the number has a remainder. I tried using this function, but it always seems to mess up, even though in theory it does work. Any help is appreciated. Also, I could use pointers, but am not too sure how to use them in this particular case.

```
int main(void)
{
    int arr[5];
    int tC = 39;
    int i;

    for(i=0; i<5; i++)
    {
        if(tC%2==0)
            arr[i] = 0;
        else
            arr[i] = 1;
        tC/=2;
    }
    printf("\n%d\n", arr[5]);
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just a little change required:

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main(void)
{
    int arr[5];
    int tC = 39;
    int i;

    for(i=4; i>=0; i--)
    {
        if(tC%2==0)
            arr[i] = 0;
        else
            arr[i] = 1;
        tC/=2;
    }
    for(i=0; i<5; i++)
        printf("%d", arr[i]);
}
```

Since you are storing the binary values in an array and looping from 0-4 (<5) - the values are getting saved in reverse order. You just need to loop from 4-0 (0 included). Also, in `printf` you were printing the individual bit value stored in the `arr[5]` which is `UB` since the last index is 4 - also, you were not looping to print all bit values in your array.